# Meteor: access one property inside nested object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this MongoDB query that returns an object (document)

```js
var myFavSports = Profile.findOne({userId: currentUser, 'favsports.name': league});
```

Here's what I log to console:

```js
Object {_id: "sxberS7dGh3jwkann", userId: "59Pfb4MZy9WyAqqxc", userLevel: "Level 1", userLevelDescription: "Free Level", userLevelExpiration: Thu Jan 01 2099 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)…}
_id: "sxberS7dGh3jwkann"
aboutMe: "Description not provided"
avatarImage: "http://meteor.com/images/avatarplaceholder.png"
favsports: Array[3]
0: Object
name: "GER Bund"
selfrank: "3"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
name: "NBA"
selfrank: "2"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
name: "NHL"
selfrank: "1"
```

So, if I supply "GER Bund" to this template helper, it should return 3 (selfrank)

Instead, it returns the whole document, matched on userID and league, but how do I get "3" out of it to display in the template.

I tried .notation, and it always returns "undefined". I tried printing to console as myFavSports.favsports[0].rank, then it works, but it is not the correct match, because hardcoded index 0 is not the match.

Comment: Then iterate over `favsports` to find a proper name.

Comment: Do you mean inside template or template helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Minimongo doesn't yet support the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator in **[field specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers)**, a workaround would be to use the **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method on the returned array to filter the elements:

```
   var query = { "userId": currentUser, "favsports.name": league };
   var myFavSports = Profile.findOne(query).favsports
                            .filter(function(s) { 
                                return s.name === league 
                            })[0] ;

console.log(myFavSports); // logs { name: "GER Bund", selfrank: "3"}
console.log(myFavSports.name); // logs "GER Bund"
console.log(myFavSports.selfrank); // logs "3"
```

---

In mongo shell, you would use the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator in your projection as this will automatically limit the contents of `favsports`array from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document. Thus you can obtain the desired object as follows:

```
var query = { "userId": currentUser, "favsports.name": league },
    projection = { "_id": 0, "favsports.$": 1 },
    myFavSports = db.profile.findOne(query, projection).favsports[0];

console.log(myFavSports); // logs { name: "GER Bund", selfrank: "3"}
console.log(myFavSports.name); // logs "GER Bund"
console.log(myFavSports.selfrank); // logs "3"
```

Comment: This sounded interesting, but getting an error: 
6debug.js:41 Exception in template helper: MinimongoError: Minimongo doesn't support $ operator in projections yet.

Comment: @FloridaGard I've updated the solution to include a workaround for this constraint.

Comment: Sorry, still no go. Another error: Exception in template helper: Error: You may not observe a cursor with {fields: {_id: 0}} .

Comment: My apologies, I haven't tested this so you may want to give it another go, the projection in this case isn't quite necessary since you ill be filtering the `favsports` property.

Comment: @FloridaGard No worries, happy to help :)